# Can't Insert data into database using Android Volley Library

Tags: php, android

I am trying to insert data to my website SQL database using Volley library. I tried many times from different sources but i can't find any solution. There are some couples of solutions in stack over flow, but still I found some problems.
**Problem:**

---

My PHP code(**insert.php**):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "id953167_gonitniketon";
$password = "gonitniketon24";
$dbname = "id953167_dada_db";

$regi = "";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $regi = $_POST['regi'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO insert_std(regi) VALUES ('$regi')";

    if(mysqli_query($conn, $query)){
    echo "Successfully Registered";
    }else{
    echo $regi." Not Registered";
    }

}else{
    echo 'error';
}
?>
```

---

**Java Code:**

```
    final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    final String url ="http://gonitniketan.site90.com/insert.php";

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String regi = et.getText().toString().trim();

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                            Toast.makeText(test.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            Toast.makeText(test.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("regi",regi);

                    return params;
                }

            };

            queue.add(stringRequest);


        }
    });
```

---

It always shows the toast of Not Registered.I think, this POST method can't insert data to my database. 
I can't find any solution.

Comment: Can you print out the full SQL error message or error code with `mysqli_error($conn)`, please?

Comment: I use this
echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn);

But through error response method it shows null.

Comment: Have you tested the API using Postman or something similar?

Comment: No. I know something about Retrofit API but i can't apply this. Primarily i tried to apply Volley library to insert data. Using this I can fetch data from Database. Facing problem in case of inserting data.

Comment: I would recommend installing postman and successfully consuming the API and sharing the screenshot, so we can figure out whether the params go in getParams or getBody

Comment: I have updated my **insert.php** `echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn);`  .I used Postman and the screenshot link [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7qzEunJ65E0Vk1DYWxqQk5zYWc/view

Comment: try putting the key and value in body instead of params

Comment: link 1 https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7qzEunJ65E0SzBYRFFrRkFnVUU  link2 https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7qzEunJ65E0YzB3Q3dTcng1aXc